# rxjs conditional startWith , endWith using iif operator

Tags: rxjs, iif

Still figuring rxjs out and its a great library (have to admit). Given that we have this source and booleans.

```
let source = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let swEnabled = false;
let ewEnabled = false;
```

And we would like to conditionally enable startwith and endwith operators based on swEnabled and ewEnabled to the source.....

```
source.pipe(
        iif(() => swEnabled,startWith(1000),),
        iif(() => ewEnabled,endWith(1000),),
        ).subscribe( 
        (n)=>{
               console.log(n);
           });
```

but no joy..... anyone can provide an example of this? Maybe the approach is wrong. Or can you suggest some alternative approach ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally build an array of operators as follows:

```
import { MonoTypeOperatorFunction, of } from 'rxjs';
import { pipeFromArray } from 'rxjs/internal/util/pipe';
import { endWith, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

let source = of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
let swEnabled = false;
let ewEnabled = false;
let operators: MonoTypeOperatorFunction<number>[] = []

if (swEnabled) {
  operators.push(startWith(1000))
}

if (ewEnabled) {
  operators.push(endWith(1000))
}

source.pipe(pipeFromArray(operators)).subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3989) about not being able to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) inside the `pipe`. If that issue gets fixed, then you will no longer need the `pipeFromArray` function and the solution can be simplified to `source.pipe(...operators)`.

Re `iif`: Note that the `iif` function is an Observable constructor function and not an operator function. That means that you cannot use `iif` as an operator inside `pipe()` as you have shown. By observing the [RxJx reference page](https://rxjs.dev/api), you can see that there are two sections, amongst others, titled `index` and `operators`. Only the functions under `operators` can be used directly within the `pipe()`. The functions under `index` can be used to construct source Observables.

Re `startWith` and `endWith`: These two functions are operator functions (meant to be used inside `pipe`) and not Observables. The `iif` function expects an Observable as the second and third argument.

Comment: first of all super thanks for your prompt reply. So are you saying that the 'reasoning' behind the code i provided was good but due to the mentioned 'open issue' the code cannot work ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to address the use of `iif`. But no, the open issue has nothing to do with the code you provided. It's only related to the solution I provided. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same question, but after trying different strategies I came up with this solution:

```
someObservable.pipe(
  // anyOperator(),
  condition ? conditionalOperator() : tap(() => {})
)
```

In this case, if condition is true, `operatorA` is added to pipe, if not, the `tap(() => {})` is like a "noop" (anyone can mix the condition and parameters to fit any needs).